# Error in VBA Macro when downloading historical stock prices for one specific ticker: MDB

Tags: excel, vba

I created a spreadsheet to download historical financials from Yahoo Finance.   It works well for any stock except for MDB.  On an empty sheet input the following formula in cell B8:

="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"&B7&"?period1=11750400&period2=1589414400&interval=1d&events=history"

On cell B7 I input the stock Yahoo Finance Ticker (for instance, for Intel Corporation is INTC.)

The macro is very simple:

```
Sub Download_Stock_Price_History()
    Dim Ticker As String
    Let Ticker = Range("B8").Value
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Ticker, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Range("F1").Select

End Sub
```

What is most intriguing is that it seems that it downloads the MDB data, but Excel crashes.  Then it re-opens alone in the starting file (the one w/ the macro) with the formula bar hidden otherwise working normally.

Can somebody test this on their PC in Excel and see if they get an error JUST with MDB?  (I've tried it with many tickers without problem but JUST get a problem with MDB.)

Thank you and best,
Pablo

Comment: The problem might be on their end. They have a bug which causes the information for MDB (and perhaps other stocks -- did you really test *all* other stocks?) to be malformed. If this is the case, you can either look at whatever it is that they give you in this case and find how to extract the information, or use error-handling so that at least your code doesn't crash when it encounters anomalous data.

Comment: Thank you John.  I tried the following stocks:  SHOP
ZM
DOCU
COUP
OKTA
TEAM
XRO.AX
VEEV
AYX
ADBE
NOW
MDB
BL
APPF
SREV
ZS
DDOG
CRM
QTWO
ZEN
TWLO
FSCT
BOX
WORK
PVS.AX
CLDR
ECOM
ESTC
WDAY
SCWX
PD
WK
YEXT
CSOD
TLND
MSFT
NVDA
AMZN
AAPL
NFLX
INTC
GOOG
FB
%5EIXIC
%5EGSPC                   They all worked except for MDB